# Create a status list in SharePoint 2013

Tags: list, web-part

I need to create a status list in SharePoint 2013 and want to display the items with indicators on the page using the status webpart. Can anyone please guide me as I'm not able to create the status list because of which I'm struggling to configure the status webpart.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the below URL's to achieve your requirement

http://eimagine.com/creating-a-stoplight-color-coded-status-in-a-sharepoint-2013-list/

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/getting-started-with-sharepoint-status-indicators-604ede4f-0aa7-46f9-be37-a188bee0173d